# AWS API Gateway: multiple authentication methods for an endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

Is it possible to have multiple authentication methods for an endpoint under AWS API Gateway.

For example, I want to let user able to be authenticated thru one of the following methods:

1. JWT token
2. AWS API Keys